# Javascript: number is randomized only when the page is refreshed. Needs to refresh on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**UPDATED 13:22pm** I added a button to play a random song. The code given below works fine. However, when the random track finishes playing, and the play button is clicked again, same track plays. It only randomizes after a page is refreshed.

What I am trying to do is, randomize the tracks each time the button is clicked without the need to refresh the page

I replaced src values with xxx just for this example

**HTML:-**

```
<audio id="audiotag1" src="xxx" preload="auto" onended="iconReset1();"></audio>
<audio id="audiotag2" src="xxx" preload="auto" onended="iconReset2();"></audio>
<audio id="audiotag3" src="xxx" preload="auto" onended="iconReset3();"></audio>

<a href="javascript:playTrackR();">
   <img id="playR" src="img/playR.gif">
</a>
                                                                    
<a href="javascript:pauseTrackR();">
   <img id="pauseR" src="img/pauseR.gif">
</a>
```

**javascript:-**

```
  var tracks = [ "audiotag1","audiotag2","audiotag3"];
  
  var randomTrack = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random()*tracks.length)];
    
  function playTrackR(){
    document.getElementById(randomTrack).play();
    document.getElementById('playR').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('pauseR').style.display = "block";
   }

  function pauseTrackR() {
    document.getElementById(randomTrack).pause();
    document.getElementById('pauseR').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('playR').style.display = "block";
   }
```

Comment: Put code `randomTrack = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random()*tracks.length)];` in your `playTrackR` function

Answer (score 0):

you must generate the random number inside the play function:

```
var tracks = [ "audiotag1","audiotag2","audiotag3"],
    randomTrack = 0;

function playTrackR()
{
  randomTrack = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random()*tracks.length)];

  document.getElementById(randomTrack).play();
  document.getElementById('playR').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('pauseR').style.display = "block";
  }

function pauseTrackR()
{
  document.getElementById(randomTrack).pause();
  document.getElementById('pauseR').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('playR').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: pause(); function no longer reacts to clicks when I applied your attempted solution

Answer (score 0):

Change your `playTrackR()` method to include `var randomTrack = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random()*tracks.length)];`

Like so:

```
function playTrackR(){
  var randomTrack = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random()*tracks.length)];
  document.getElementById(randomTrack).play();
  document.getElementById('playR').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('pauseR').style.display = "block";
}
```

This way, `randomTrack` is set to a new randomly generated number every time `playTrackR()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/ended_(Web_Audio)) event. Like in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/5PPzL/1/):

**HTML**

```
<audio src=""></audio>
<img src="" style="width: 30px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="playPause( this );" />
```

**JS**

```
// src for play button
var playSrc = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/Crystal_Project_Player_play.png";
// src for pause button
var pauseSrc = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Crystal_Project_Player_pause.png";
// array with sound's srcs
var audios = [ "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/master/examples/assets/Game-Shot.ogg", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/master/examples/assets/Game-Death.ogg", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/master/examples/assets/Game-Spawn.ogg", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/master/examples/assets/Game-Break.ogg" ];
// when window full loads
window.addEventListener( "load", function( windowLoadE ) {
    // first 'img' element on the page
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName( "img" )[ 0 ];
    // set 'src' of 'img' to play
    img.src = playSrc;
    // first 'audio' element on the page
    var audio = document.getElementsByTagName( "audio" )[ 0 ];
    // set src attribute of first audio element to random src from audios array
    audio.src = audios[ Math.round( Math.random() * ( audios.length - 1 ) ) ];
    // when current audio ends
    audio.addEventListener( "ended", function( event ) {
        // first 'img' element on the page
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName( "img" )[ 0 ];
        // set 'src' of 'img' to play
        img.src = playSrc;
        // event.taget = our 'audio' tag
        // set 'src' attribute of 'audio' tag to random src from 'audios' array
        event.target.src = audios[ Math.round( Math.random() * ( audios.length - 1 ) ) ];
    } );
} );
function playPause( img ) {
    // first 'audio' element on the page
    var audio = document.getElementsByTagName( "audio" )[ 0 ];
    // if audio on pause
    if ( audio.paused ) {
        // start play
        audio.play();
        // set 'src' of 'img' to pause
        img.src = pauseSrc;
    // if audio playing
    } else {
        // set audio on pause
        audio.pause();
        // set 'src' of 'img' to play
        img.src = playSrc;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Teallaair9 sure, I'm apdate an answer and link on jsFiddle.